# Achieving a never-ending loop of game tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

The following is a basic implementation of a loop which is intended to launch a series of games in a loop (generic ones that can be overridden, but that have always have finite durations).  The intention would be that a game can broadcast events to clients and would always broadcast its completion.  When there are no clients listening it can `Shutdown`, and restart again when some clients begin listening again

Is it a good way to approach this?  Does it matter that I do not await the `_gameScheduler.Start(this)` call? Am I dealing with the task loop correctly?  Is the timer used correctly?

```
public class Table
{
    private readonly GameScheduler _gameScheduler;
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public Table()
    {
        _gameScheduler = new GameScheduler();
        Task schedulerTask = _gameScheduler.Start(this);
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        _gameScheduler.Shutdown();
    }
}

public class GameScheduler
{
    private bool _running = true;
    public async Task Start(Table t)
    {
        while (_running)
        {
            await RunGame(t);
        }
    }

    async Task RunGame(Table table)
    {
        var game = new Game();
        table.Game = game;
        table.Game.Start();
        await table.Game.GameCompletionSource.Task;
    }
    public void Shutdown() { _running = false; }
}

public class Game
{
    System.Threading.Timer _countdownTimer;
    private int _timeLeft = 15000;
    private int _countdownInterval = 1000;
    public TaskCompletionSource<bool> GameCompletionSource;
    public void Start()
    {
        _countdownTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(GameCountdown, null, 0, _countdownInterval);
    }
    public void GameCountdown(object state)
    {
        if (_timeLeft <= 0)
        {
            _countdownTimer.Dispose();
            Finish();
        }
        else
        {
            _timeLeft -= _countdownInterval;
        }
    }
    private void Finish()
    {
        GameCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! That looks like an interesting program, I'm curious what our C# experts will have to say about it. Hope you get some good reviews!

Answer (score 2):

I just want to say that I review C# code style a lot on this site, and this code made me very happy for many seconds, until I spotted this:

```
public async Task Start(Table t)
```

*So close!*

`t` should, of course, have a much more descriptive name here. You've even done that elsewhere, so it is most likely an oversight on your part.

I don't like underscore notation personally as it smells strongly *Hungarian*, but it's a commonly-accepted system in C# so I don't have a leg to stand on.

Comment: Haha! I think that t may have survived from an earlier refactoring from a situation where I was using an anonymous function. Probably not much of an excuse (and I may be making that up!)

Comment: On the underscores, interested to know which approach you prefer to differentiate private members, if any at all? Not sure where I picked up the habit but as you say it is certainly quite common in C#

Comment: It tends to come from the older C++ days, if I recall correctly, but is still common in C#. My personal preference is to simply omit underscores and rely on short methods (so I can usually always see the local declarations) to differentiate. However I should again stress that even Microsoft recommend _notation at times. Another recommended alternative is to use `this.x` when referencing local members.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense. Well I guess as long as the intention is clear and it's readable I'm happy with any approach. Thanks for the answer and the compliment